# default controller not routing to my selected controller

Tags: codeigniter

im working with a front and admin folders on codeigniter, its my 1st project, i have no problem routing to my controllers, but with the default controller, i get an 404 error.
also with the admin.
i have default controller to route to front/inicio where i have my index function.
when typing localhost/ci/inicio , its load the index function ok, within inicio.php
but when typing localhost/ci/, i get an 404 error.

Also, with routing localhost/ci/admin to admin/test, same error.
i have spent a lot of time trying to fix it. i attach a jpg with my htaccess, config and controller a view tree.

my inicio controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Inicio extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->layout->setLayout('home');
        $this->load->model('front/model_comunas');
        $this->load->model('front/model_sectores');
        $this->load->model('front/model_propiedades');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->layout->setTitle("Ventana Urbana");
        $this->layout->setDescripcion("Buscar propiedades en venta y arriendo");
        $this->layout->setKeywords("propiedades");
        $this->layout->js(array(base_url()."assets/js/buscador_home.js"));
        $this->layout->view('index');
    }
```

the content of htaccess, routes, config in this jpg.
[controllers/view/htaccess/routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33JwC.jpg)

Comment: add some code please

Comment: hi, i edited the question, and in the image is more content.

Comment: What version of CI you using because if your 3 and up you cant have default controller in sub folder unless have a suitable MY_Router http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35620564/how-to-routing-controllers-in-sub-folders-using-codeigniter-3/35620718#35620718

Comment: what you need as routing?? which path and what is the controller+method

Comment: im using codeigniter 3.0.4, i will check your link wolfgang1983, thanks,

Comment: i wish that localhost/ci/  sends me to front/inicio, and index method.

Comment: using MY_Router.php works fine with default_controller, thanks wolfgang1983,

Comment: @SantiagoVera should rename file name from `inicio` to `Inicio`. first alphabet should be capital letter. Its important in codeigniter3.

Comment: Yes, try to change filename from inicio to Inicio

Comment: thanks Yash and Jack, that is in the controllers files names?  as the name of the class, the name of the file, and in the routes ?