# Codeigniter Routing Issues on AWS EC2

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have been searching the stackoverflow all day for an answer to this and I just can't seem to find one.

I have my Codeigniter app on an AWS EC2 server.

Here is my routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/home';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/$1';
```

**EDIT** Here is my current routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/home';
$route['about'] = 'pages/about';
$route['contact'] = 'pages/contact';
$route['home'] = 'pages/home';
```

Here is my Pages.php:

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function home(){
        $this->view('home');
    }

    public function about(){
        $this->view('about');
    }

    public function contact(){
        $this->view('contact');
    }

    public function view($page)
    {
         if (!file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }

}
```

Here is my .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

My config.php:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

**PROBLEM**

If I go to (my-url), it uses my default_controller.
If I go to (my-url)/home or /about or /contact, I get a 404 error.
If I go to (my-url)/index.php/home or /about or /contact, I get the default_controller.

I have double checked that mod_rewrite is installed and enabled. I can't seem to figure out why I'm not getting anything. I followed the tutorial and read a bunch of stackoverflow questions and answers to try to solve it, but to no avail.

Please help.

Comment: Check with `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]` instead `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]`.

Comment: What version of CI are you using?

Comment: @wolfgang1983 The most recent one. 3.0.5

Comment: @Tpojka that didn't work either.

Comment: @J.Han you cannot have sub folder in default controller route in that version. You need to have a suitable MY_Router.php to enable that feature as shown  here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35620564/how-to-routing-controllers-in-sub-folders-using-codeigniter-3/35620718#35620718

Comment: I'll give that a try and update. Thanks for a lead @wolfgang1983

Comment: I misunderstood. I don't have any subfolders in my default controller. It's all controller/method

Comment: Hey Han did u fixed this error?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use routes as like that:

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/$1';
```

It will not work with all functions as you need.

**Just Suggestion:**

Use your routes as:

```
$route['about'] = 'pages/about';
$route['contact'] = 'pages/contact';
$route['view/(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
......
```

You need different routes for different URL if you use `(:any)` as first param it will not work properly for all functions.

Comment: @j-han remove this `$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/$1';`

Comment: Right now, I just changed it to:
$route['about'] = 'pages/about';

Still didn't work

Comment: I did, in separate testings:
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['about'] = 'pages/about';
$route['view/(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';

None have worked.

Comment: @j-han change yur htaccess and than use these routes

Comment: @j-han this will hurt yur all URL remove thus `$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106058/discussion-between-j-han-and-devpro).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get a 404

Answer (score 0):

Note when using APPPATH constant, the path ends with '/' already

try change

```
if (!file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
```

to

```
if (!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
```

Comment: This code from straight from Codeigniter's tutorial and has been working, so unfortunately, that's not the issue.

Comment: @J.Han actually, @wakeel is right. If you check `index.php` file you will see that constant is defined with `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` at the end. Fun fact: I proposed that change in documentation few hours ago.

Comment: While I changed it, it did nothing for my issue unfortunately. At this point, I'm tempted to ignore the MVC and just use CI for other parts that I don't have to do and use GET functions to navigate through pages.