# Codeigniter 3 sub folders

Tags: codeigniter-3

Hope you guys can help me with following:
I want to usea  nice subfolder structure like:

app/admin/customers/contacts/add

and

app/admin/customers/contacts/edit/1

Controllers and models are in same folder structure.
Due to limitations in maximum subfolder depth, the 'add' and 'edit' view files are returning a 404.
Tried several workarounds but cannot get it working. Any idea how to extend CI functionality to get it work?

Comment: Looks like you'll need to extend your router. This links talks about that so it should help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35620564/how-to-routing-controllers-in-sub-folders-using-codeigniter-3

Comment: Thanks for this direction.  I'll go through.

Answer (score 0):

Spent a lot of hours on the same issue. Troubleshooting steps:

```
-Confirm controllers & .htaccess all work for nonsubfolders
-Confirm routing works (ex. $route['sys'] = 'verify'; )
-Confirm your controller starts with a capital letter  <--solved for me
-Confirm spelling matches
```