# how to set homepage in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I organized my controllers and views into subdirectories like this

> frontend
>
> admin

I created a Home.php in *controllers/frontend*
and a
home.php file in *views/frontend*

CI is installed in http://localhost/ci

when I access http://localhost/ci, I'd like the home view to load, but currently I can only access it via http://localhost:8080/ci/frontend/home

I'm guessing it may have something to do with my .htaccess file which is this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I also created the following constant:

```
define('BASE_URL', '/');
```

In the routes.php the default controller is set to:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'frontend/home';
```

In the config.php, the base URL is set to:

```
$config['base_url'] = BASE_URL;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Out of the Box CI 3.x.x doesn't support what you want to do. It's strictly controller/method...

But a little digging found this  - [Extending the Router Class to support subfolders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35620564/how-to-routing-controllers-in-sub-folders-using-codeigniter-3)

This allows you to override the behaviour of the router class and use sub folders.