# How to make route for subfolder in codeigntier 3

Tags: routes, codeigniter-3

How to make route for subfolder in codeigntier 3?

Its working fine on Linux but not working on windows. Always give 404 error page

Comment: Please add an example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have route like - http://localhost/project/index.php/oetcomp/OetCompTest/introductionreading/40 where oetcomp is folder name inside controller directory....OetCompTest is the name of controller inside controllers/oetcomp/OetCompTestController.php and introductionreading is function name....when trying to access above url...then page not found error is coming....One more strange thing It has worked fine in LINUX but in WINDOWS its not working....Please asap

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35620564/how-to-routing-controllers-in-sub-folders-using-codeigniter-3

Answer (score 0):

First of all please remove `index.php` value from the
`application/config/config.php:38 $config['index_page'] = '';`

and second in windows os you need a `.htaccess` file to the root (project) folder, look like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1/ [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: above code only removed index.php from url.. I have another problem - I have route like - localhost/project/index.php/oetcomp/OetCompTest/… where oetcomp is folder name inside controller directory....OetCompTest is the name of controller inside controllers/oetcomp/OetCompTestController.php and introductionreading is function name....when trying to access above url...then page not found error is coming....One more strange thing It has worked fine in LINUX but in WINDOWS its not working....Please reply asap

Comment: try to create .htaccess file to the project folder

Answer (score 0):

i see the problem, your controller name is invalid, here is some example

```
project/application/controllers/oetcomp/OetCompTest.php 
localhost/project/oetcomp/oetcomptest/function_name


project/application/controllers/Main.php
localhost/project/main/function_name

project/application/controllers/users/manage/Add.php
localhost/project/users/manage/add/function_name
```

Comment: Not working..please give me another solution

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Each of your sub-directories may contain a default controller which will be called if the URL contains only the sub-directory. Simply put a controller in there that matches the name of your ‘default_controller’ as specified in your application/config/routes.php file.

how to set Each of your sub-directories may contain a default controller?

Please reply anyone